# how to PUT in Postman to change Woocommerce REST API meta_data

Tags: rest, woocommerce, postman, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to change a key-value pair in woocommerce using `put` in postman, but just cannot get ANY data to change.

I know it works from our ERP system, where I just put the key and value and it does its magic. But I want to learn and be able to test some other scenarios manually.

1. I have set up the REST API consumer_key and consumer_secret in woo
2. It is set to read AND write
3. I can use a `GET` and get a correct reply with info
4. Now I would like to `PUT` a specific meta_data field.
5. I am on the correct server (checked the url) and I get Status 200ok, but nothing changes

Assuming this is the reply from `GET` (just made it shorter)

```
   {
        "id": 123445,
        "name": "Productname",
        "meta_data": [
            {
                "id": 121796,
                "key": "_product_checkbox",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I actually want to change the value of `_product_checkbox`, but even if I try just `name`, I have no success.

These are my `PUT` settings:

```
staging102.ourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/123445?consumer_key=ck_something&consumer_secret=cs_somethingelse
```

and then I tried in Body > raw > JSON

```
{"name":"Postmantest"}
```

and also separately

```
{
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "key": "_product_checkbox",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

It always returns with status 200 and ok, but there is just nothing at all happening. What am I doing wrong, what have I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: any suggestions at all?